# Call function from Activity Class after preferences are updated Android

Tags: java, android

I would like to call a function from my main activity class after my preferences are updated, but I can't use `onResume()` because I have other classes that will trigger `onResume` (I believe).

Snippet from `AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.settings:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`SettingsActivity.java`:

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

After my preferences close, I want to call a function from my Main Activity, however it MUST be from my main activity because I need to send a context from my Main Activity. I've tried so much and just can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 0):

`onResume()` is triggered when the `Activity` comes to the foreground. You should never be "triggering" `onResume()` other than leaving/returning to the Activity (if you're ever directly calling `onResume()`, you're doing it wrong).

Assuming you're needing to check for the updated value when you return to your Activity, then yes, `onResume()` is where you should probably do that. If the user returns to MainActivity after viewing SettingsActivity, then `onResume()` will be called, and you can check the updated preference value there.

EDIT: So I think honestly you'd be better off checking the preference values in `onResume()`, and not caching them globally. They aren't expensive to look up. Also, for immediate notifications, you could register a listener for preference changes, like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        registerPreferenceListener();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterPreferenceListener();
    }

    private void registerPreferenceListener() {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    private void unregisterPreferenceListener() {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if ("the_key_i'm_interested_in".equals(key)) {
            // Update stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I come from another activity though? Then I don't want `onResume()` to be called.

Comment: `onResume()` will *always* be called when being brought to the foreground, regardless of which path brought you there.

Comment: But I only want `onResume()` called after preferences. That's exactly what the question was attempting to ask.

Comment: Well then the answer is no. That's part of the framework and is a guaranteed event. What is your goal?

Comment: To update all preference values when they are set. I have a global class doing so.

Comment: So you're keeping a local cache of preference values somewhere?

Comment: Yes, in classes like public `getHost(){return host;}`